# PHP variable as part of a jQuery function doesn't work, but plain text does

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code in my PHP file *(edited Jan 19 2010 @ 10:40 MST)*:

```
<?php
   $count = 0;
   foreach($attachments as $attachment) :
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
               $(\'#a_'.$count.'\').click(function() {
                  $(\'#d_'.$count.'\').show(200);
               });

               // if "no" is clicked
               $(\'#d_'.$count.' .no\').click(function() {
                  $(\'#d_'.$count.'\').hide(200);
               });

               // if "yes" is clicked
               $(\'#d_'.$count.' .yes\').click(function() {
                  $(\'#d_'.$count.'\').hide(200);

                  // update database table -- this is why I need the script inside the for loop!
                  var jsonURL = \'http://path/to/update_db_script.php\';
                  $.getJSON(jsonURL, {\'post_id\' : '.$attachment->ID.'}, function(data) {
                     alert(\'Thank you. Your approval was received.\');
                  });
                  $(\'#a_'.$count.'\').replaceWith(\'<span>Approved</span>\');
               });
            </script>';

      echo '<li>';
         if($attachment->post_excerpt == 'approved') {
            // Check the proof's status to see if it reads "approved"
            echo '<span>Approved</span>';
         } else { ?>
            // If not yet approved, show options
            <a class="approve" id="a_<?php echo $count; ?>" href="#">Click to Approve</a>
            <div class="confirm-approval" id="d_<?php echo $count; ?>">
               <p>Please confirm that you would like to approve this proof:</p>
               <a class="yes" href="#">Yes, I approve</a>
               <a class="no" href="#">No, not yet</a>
            </div><?php
         } ?>
      </li>
   <?php $count++;
endforeach; ?>
```

[The page in question is available here](http://www.usfoldercompany.com/wordpress/proofs/). The "click to approve" links do not work (that's my problem).

When I view source, the PHP variables appear to have echoed properly inside the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#a_0').click(function() {
      $('#d_0').show(200);
   });
   ... etc ...
</script>
```

This looks correct, but nothing happens when I click any of the links. However, **when I replace the PHP echo statements with plain numbers (0, 1, etc.) the click functions work as expected**.

You may be asking: *why on earth do you have this inside a for loop?* The reason is that I need to retrieve the **attachment->ID** variable and pass it to an external PHP script. When someone clicks "approve" and confirms, the external script takes the attachment->ID and updates a database value to read "approved".

**Why won't the click function fire when PHP is in place?** Is there some kind of greater force at work here (e.g., hosting limitation), or am I missing a fundamental piece of how PHP and JavaScript interact?

Comment: are you actually writing document.ready() or was it $(document).ready() ?

Comment: it's as you say -- $(document).ready() { ... });

Comment: Ryan, your page is throwing a `loadArray is not defined` error referencing line 222 in jq_priceCalc.js. Can you fix that first? There is a remote possibility this is masking your problem.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for posting your updated code. You still do not need the loop, even seeing your code, but please post a comment here when the `loadArray` error is fixed so I can troubleshoot the rest of the page since it all looks correct.

Comment: @Ryan, one more thing. Move your actual `HTML` elements to print before the `script` element in the loop instead of after as you have it now.

Comment: Doug, you're the man. I fixed the **loadArray** issue, but that wasn't it; moving the HTML elements before the **<script>** piece fixed the problem. Why is this?

I'm aware that printing a separate **<script>** each iteration of the loop is a bit inefficient. You mentioned not needing a loop, so I'm curious if there is a better way to do what I'm after. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you didn't post your HTML its a little hard to troubleshoot.

First, I am not sure why one is working and the other is not since the code it is outputting looks correct. Either way, I still would make some changes. Move your `a_0`,`a_1`, etc and `d_0`,`d_1`, etc into the `id` attribute instead of a class:

```
<div><a href="#" id="a_0" class="approve">Click Me</a></div>
<div class="confirm_approval" id="d_0">Show Me</div>
<div><a href="#" id="a_1" class="approve">Click Me</a></div>
<div class="confirm_approval" id="d_1">Show Me</div>
```

Now, instead of outputting your code in a loop in PHP, place this jQuery code *once* on your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a.approve[id^='a_']").click(function(e){
      var id = this.id.replace('a_',''); // Get the id for this link
      $('#d_' + id + '.confirm-approval').show(200);
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

This code finds any `a` element with the `approve` class that has an `id` that *starts with* `a_`. When this is clicked, it grabs the number off the id `a_0 = 0` and uses that id to find the `confirm-approval` element and show it.

Comment: Doug, that's a fantastic way of doing things; thank you. I still don't understand why echoing PHP into the jQuery would cause it to fail, while replacing the variables with a fixed number allows it to succeed. So while I now have a great solution for future reference, I'm still at an impasse in this case.

Comment: I updated my question to include additional relevant code. The idea is to show everyone why I included the jQuery inside a for loop instead of just once in the <head>.

Answer (score 2):

Since the javascript is run on the client and has no way of knowing whether the script was generated using PHP or not, I think that particular part is a wild goose chase...

> When I replace the PHP echo statements
>   with plain numbers (0, 1, etc.) the
>   click function works as expected.

Do this again and compare the actual output using view-source in a browser. I'll bet you find that there is a difference between the working and failing scripts, other than one of them being generated by PHP.

Comment: Grossvogel, thanks for the response. I checked the source code for both PHP and plain text output, and they are identical. If I'm correct, PHP is parsed before the page hits the browser, so either way JavaScript should see just a plain number.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in jQuery selectors. Instead of dynamically binding `click()` events on multiple objects with an output of PHP code, use just one class selector and bind to objects with this class. And you can specify an `id` attribute to make them unique.

Comment: Darmen, I just updated my code so that everything has unique IDs. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the problem; variables echoed by PHP still cause trouble, while static numbers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something strange too is to have the script tag and the

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

in the loop. I don't know if this causes any problems, but it's sure not very efficient, one time is enough.

Comment: I know...you're right, but the overall script (not shown) is more complicated. The reason I have the jQuery piece inside a for loop is because I need PHP a variable that's only present in this loop. The variable is sent via .getJSON to another PHP script. I haven't yet come up with a creative way to get this variable outside of the for loop.